# Question about definition of continuity and the choice of distance.

Tags: real-analysis

We have the following definition of continuity:

Let $E \in \mathbb R^k, F \in \mathbb R^m$. Let $f: E \rightarrow F$ be a function.

We say that $f$ is continuous in $x_0 \in E$  iff

$\forall  \epsilon >0  \ \exists \delta >0 , \ (x \in E,  \ d(x,x_0)<\delta) \rightarrow d(f(x_0),f(x))<\epsilon$.

My question:

I know that this statement does not depend on the chosen distance, but do the distance functions between $(x,x_0)$ and $(f(x_0),f(x))$ have to be the same or can we choose two different distance functions (for example the chebyshev distance on the two points  and the euclidan distance on their images) and check the definition to see if $f$ is continuous or not?

Comment: Continuity does not necessarily depend on the metric, but on the topology induced by that metric. if two metrics induce the same topology, then you may choose either in the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make any difference which distance you choose, as long both distances generate the same topology, that is, for each $x\in E$, $\epsilon > 0$ there are a $\epsilon', \epsilon'' > 0$ such that 
$$ \{x' \in E \mid d_1(x,x') < \epsilon\} \subseteq \{x' \in E \mid d_2(x,x') < \epsilon'\}$$
and $$ \{x' \in E \mid d_2(x,x') < \epsilon\} \subseteq \{x' \in E \mid d_1(x,x'') < \epsilon'\}. $$
Same for distances in $F$.

This is for example fulfilled, if there are $c,C > 0$ such that
$$ c\cdot d_1(x,x') < d_2(x,x') < C\cdot d_1(x,x') $$
for all $x,x'\in E$ (as for Euclidean and Chebychev distance).

Comment: that was my thought, good to see it confirmed.Thanks.